# Celery - Programmatically list workers

Tags: python, celery

How can I programmatically, using Python code, list current workers and their corresponding `celery.worker.consumer.Consumer` instances?

Answer (score 31):

You can use [celery.control.inspect](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/workers.html#inspecting-workers) to inspect the running workers:

```
>>> import celery
>>> celery.current_app.control.inspect().ping()
 {u'celery@host': {u'ok': u'pong'}}
```

Comment: nice one, with this i can build a REST API that asks if the workers are up or if they crashed and notify the user

Comment: is there a timeout option?

Comment: @technazi you can set timeout when instantiating the `inspect` class (defaults to 1.0): see https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.app.control.html#celery.app.control.Inspect Eg, `your_celery_app.control.inspect(timeout=2.0)`

Answer (score 13):

Short answer:

`your_celery_app.control.inspect().stats().keys()`

In general that `stats()` dictionary gives a lot of info. Here's an example value:

```
{u'broker': {u'alternates': [],
             u'connect_timeout': 4,
             u'heartbeat': 0,
             u'hostname': u'mypcisdabom',
             u'insist': False,
             u'login_method': u'AMQPLAIN',
             u'port': 5672,
             u'ssl': False,
             u'transport': u'amqp',
             u'transport_options': {},
             u'uri_prefix': None,
             u'userid': u'celeryabuser',
             u'virtual_host': u'celeryvhost'},
 u'clock': u'182309',
 u'pid': 1660,
 u'pool': {u'max-concurrency': 1,
           u'max-tasks-per-child': u'N/A',
           u'processes': [2496],
           u'put-guarded-by-semaphore': True,
           u'timeouts': [0, 0],
           u'writes': u'N/A'},
 u'prefetch_count': 4,
 u'rusage': u'N/A',
 u'total': {u'mymodule.my_func': 8}},
```

Answer (score 1):

If you will add `--events` key when starting. You can check this module for check current workers and etc. http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use **unpacking generalization** in python + **stats()** to get celery workers as list:

```
[*celery.control.inspect().stats().keys()]
```

**Reference:**
https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/monitoring.html
https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/